# High performance red-filter on Java BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, colors, filter

Let's say I have a `BufferedImage` with `ARGB` channels. I can turn this image into a grayscale image simply by doing

```
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),  
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
Graphics g = copy.getGraphics().create();  
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);  
g.dispose();
```

There are a couple of other methods to do grayscale conversion I'm aware of, but this one works good for my program. I can also (and do) enhance the contrast of the image by doing this:

```
RescaleOp op;
op = new RescaleOp(1.0f, darken, null);
op.filter(copy, copy);
op = new RescaleOp(brighten, 0.0f, null);
op.filter(copy, copy);
```

But there's a problem. Sometimes there are slightly dark-red parts of my image that I need to isolate, which are close to slightly bright regions, that is, regions with a high red value (such as yellow and purple). I need to isolate these red regions. How can I do this efficiently?

Manually, I would like something like

```
for each pixel p in original
    new.p = grayscale(Math.max(Math.abs(p.red - p.green), Math.abs(p.red - p.blue)))
```

Can I do this more efficiently using built-in filters or the like? I'm not looking for an exact filter - just something to help me on the way of isolating these red areas a bit. This kind of code makes me think there's an efficient way: this is for producing lower-quality grayscale images, but it is very fast.

```
ImageFilter filter = new GrayFilter(true, 50);  
ImageProducer producer = new FilteredImageSource(colorImage.getSource(), filter);  
Image mage = this.createImage(producer);
```

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: Either way you'd iterate right? Or iterate in 5px intervals.

Comment: Maybe, but there might be optimized library tricks you can do this fast with, like `RedImageFilter(...)` or something. Speed is essential in this part of the program.

Comment: If you're looking for a library or such, that would be off topic... OpenCV could work.

Comment: Just a side comment: Using the old `ImageSource`, `ImageProducer` and `ImageConsumer` API isn't recommended for `BufferedImage`s (they seem fast, but only because `Image`s fetches pixels asynchronously, in contrast to `BufferedImage`s). Use `BufferedImageOp`s or `RasterOp`s. :-)